How do I measure the regularity of the distribution in a list of binary data?
Suppose I have a list = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], which gives information about whether a person was sick on a day ($1$) or not ($0$), since the list has 15 elements, I consider the days 1-15. I now want to determine how "nicely" or regularly these sick days are distributed over the period.
A regular distribution would be, for example [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
an unsightly one would be e.g:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
I was thinking of either the Gini coefficient or the standard deviation of the distances. But I don't know how to deal with such a list for the second one, for example.
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Here, the value for the standard deviation of the distances would be 0, but the 1s are not well distributed.
What other possibilities are there?

One approach is to compute the autocorrelation of the series, which measures the linear relationship between lagged values of a time series.
Quoting the authors of the above link:

When data are seasonal, the autocorrelations will be larger for the
seasonal lags (at multiples of the seasonal frequency) than for other
lags.

For your two lists:

y_1 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]: the autocorrelation with lag value $2$ is 0.666
y_2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]: for all lag values $>0$, the autocorrelation is smaller than 0.666, which suggests that there is more "structure" in the first list.


Thanks for your answer. Would I be able to compare lists via the $p$ or the $z$-value?

Yes, you could compare the maximum autocorrelations, I have edited my post.

Thanks. One final question. How do i know the correct number of lags?

Either by inspection, or by plotting the autocorrelation for each possible lag, which yields the ACF plot. Check the link in the answer, it is well explained.

would a negative value be even better?

It could be Better if the absolute value is larger than 0.666

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
